# Select rows and columns in QTableWidget, while keeping highlighted

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtableview, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget that I've set up such that you can't select the cells, but can select rows/columns by their headers. The problem I'm having is when I select a row, it deselects any columns that were selected, and same for column/rows. I want to be able to select rows with the ExtendedSelection behavior and columns with the SingleSelection behavior, but independently of eachother. Here's what I'm doing:

```
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
connect(ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)), this,SLOT(horizontalHeaderClicked(int)));
connect(ui->tableWidget->verticalHeader(),SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)), this,SLOT(verticalHeaderClicked(int)));
```

Then:

```
void MatrixWidget::horizontalHeaderClicked(int column){
   if(column <= 0) return; //first column is names, doesn't represent a segment

   ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
   ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectColumns);
   ui->tableWidget->selectColumn(column);
   ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

}

```
void MatrixWidget::verticalHeaderClicked(int row){
   ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
   ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
   ui->tableWidget->selectRow(row);
   ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

This code allows you to select column first then you must press control to select other rows. Try this, I hope it can help. Anyway, this solution doesn't work well with shift.

```
void SO_Qt::hhSelected( int index )
{
    if(index <= 0) return;
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectColumns);
    ui.tableWidget->selectColumn(index);
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
}

void SO_Qt::vhSelected( int index )
{
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);
    ui.tableWidget->selectRow(index);
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to be able to do this without needing to press cntrl. I think I just need to figure out how to call selectcolumns without deselecting rows and vice versa. This might be Qt source that I can't change, so I may have to look in to using a selection model, but I found that pretty confusing.

Comment: So you have to implement it yourself. Qt [document](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemview.html) says it requires holding Ctrl key for selecting multi rows. Hope you find a solution :)