# search and highlight the items in a qtablewidget

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, qtablewidget, pyqt5

I'm using Python and PyQt and I have created a QTableWidget which I populate with data.
Is there a way to search for a specific value and if the program finds something, can it hightlight the rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `list-of-QTableWidgetItem QTableWidget.findItems (self, QString text, Qt.MatchFlags flags)` to find your specific items.

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#findItems

After this iterate throw this list and use `QTableWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor (self, QColor color)` for example to highlight this item

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#setBackgroundColor

To highlight whole row you can use `setBackgroundColor` for every item in the table(with given row) or if you want to select rows, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790509/select-rows-and-columns-in-qtablewidget-while-keeping-highlighted) or just `selectRow()`

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtableview.html#selectRow